# Запятая перед «и так далее»

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

В книге А. Пиперски «Конструирование языков: от эсперанто до дотракийского» есть предложение:

> Скажем, носитель русского языка может вспомнить слова *бланк* и *уникальный* <...>, в английском языке есть слово *blank* 'пустой', и так далее.

Зачем перед вторым союзом *и* поставлена запятая? Для того чтобы избежать ошибочного прочтения «пустой и так далее»?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Благодарю Вас от всей души. Но я немного смущена. Вы не ошиблись?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова добрый вечер! Рад, что вы оценили мой выбор ) Нет, не ошибся; я считаю, что качественно оформленное особое мнение заслуживает награды, пусть даже есть некоторые спорные части :)

Comment: Какой неожиданный поворот событий, но при этом какой приятный! Благодарю Вас ещё раз. Сегодня мой день).

Comment: Спасибо _вам_! И остальным отвечающим тоже! (Я, конечно, поставил всем плюс.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У нас сложное предложение. В его составе простые: "Носитель русского языка может..." и "В английском языке есть...". Слова "и так далее" нужно рассматривать как связанные с этим рядом. Скорее всего, здесь действует указание Розенталя не ставить запятую (см. [§ 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)), хотя он и говорит о случае, когда слова "и так далее" стоят после ряда однородных членов, а у нас есть ряд простых предложений. Подтверждением служат ответы Грамоты:

> Вопрос № 280409
>   Верна ли пунктуация? В частности, интересуют запятые перед «и».
>   Стены застыли, солнце потухло, небо посерело, и так далее, и тому подобное.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Корректно: Стены застыли, солнце потухло, небо посерело и так далее и тому подобное.
>
> Вопрос № 230461
>    Скажите, пожалуйста, как ставится запятая перед "и так далее", "и т.д." Так, нужна ли она в такой фразе: "Во время Адвента в первое воскресенье зажигают одну свечу, во второе - две, и так далее".
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Слова *и так далее, и тому подобное* (и их сокращения) не выступают в роли однородных членов предложения, запятая перед ними не ставится: *Во время Адвента в первое воскресенье зажигают одну свечу, во второе – две и так далее*.
>
> Вопрос № 212210
>    Скажите, правомерна ли запятая в скобках: Дайме подчинялся сегуну, командующий армией самураев подчинялся дайме, рядовой самурай командующему(,) и так далее? Пожалуйста, ответьте побыстрее!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Указанная запятая не требуется.

Answer (score 4):

Слова и т. д. (и так далее), и т. п. (и тому подобное) не выступают в роли однородных членов предложения, и запятая перед ними не ставится, даже если союз и повторяется перед предшествующими однородными членами: ***В этот цикл естественных наук входят и биология, и физика, и химия и т. д.; На выставку можно представить и рисунки, и этюды, и наброски и т.д.***

**См. Справочник по пунктуации. Д.Э. Розенталь.**

Comment: Это другой случай, с данным вашим ответом я знаком. Кстати, не могли бы вы указать соответствующий параграф в справочнике Розенталя?

Comment: § 13 п.10 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101 Думаю, запятая в любом случае не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрел остальные 20+ случаев употребления "и так далее" в этой книге. Как в том анекдоте: "никакой закономерности!". В некоторых случаях запятая стоит, в других — точно таких же — нет.

> Местоимения получаются из знаков 'человек' или (для женского рода) 'женщина' с подстрочным индексом 1–3, обозначающим лицо: İ1 'я', İ2 'ты', İ3 'он' и так далее.
>
> ... Will have protected' и так далее.
>
> ... В языке сольресоль лицам соответствуют ноты по порядку, и так далее.
>
> ...Papenom 'это (букв. он) пишется', päpenom 'это писалось' и так далее.

И так далее :)

Присоединяюсь к ответу **Серж** — запятая не нужна. (Я только косвенную аргументацию добавил.)

Answer (score 2):

**В Вашем примере запятую нужно поставить.** Здесь всё очень просто: завершилось простое предложение, выражение "и так далее" в него не входит. Но вопрос о постановке запятой перед "и так далее" меня интересует давно, поэтому делюсь своими размышлениями на эту тему.

*И так далее* - это **предложение**, безличное. Ср.: *И так [идёт, будет, пойдёт] далее.* Значение выражения "что-то происходит примерно так же, как в ранее перечисленных случаях".

**Запятая нужна** в любом случае - и после однородных членов, и после простых предложений в составе сложного. (Но на практике, к сожалению, очень часто запятая не ставится.)

Примеры с запятой из Нацкорпуса: ***«Нх» превращается в «нг», «а» ― в «е», «к» ― в «г», причем во всех словах языка именно в таких позициях (в начале слова, между гласными, в открытом/закрытом слоге, и так далее). [Ирина Прусс, Федор Алексеев. Hhora по-такорийски «язык» // «Знание-сила», 2014

И в вопросах православия, и в вопросах культуры, семейных ценностей, и так далее. [Сергей Доренко. Левые силы - перезагрузка (2003) // «Завтра», 2003.08.13]***

Если же это предложение оформлено как *и т.д.*, то тогда запятую можно не ставить, так как выражение выступает уже как знак, условное обозначение, а не как отдельное предложение.

По-другому рассматриваем оборот *и  тому подобное.* Значение его  "нечто такое же, как только что перечисленное."

Перед ним запятая не ставится, так по структуре своей выражение не является предложением и указывает на возможный в этом месте однородный член предложения.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: ***Поэтому всегда берут лишнюю единицу, подставную фигуру, деньги которой и уходят на перемотку и тому подобное. [Анатолий Азольский. Лопушок // «Новый Мир», 1998]***

Выражение "и так далее и тому подобное" является фразеологизмом, оформляем его без запятой между оборотами, но перед выражением в целом запятую всё-таки лучше поставить.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: ***Какие-то обозы…, некрасивые люди, танки, танки со звёздами, танки с крестами, поля горят, громкая музыка, самолёты воют, и так далее и тому подобное. [Евгений Гришковец. ОдноврЕмЕнно (2004)]***

Очень часто этот фразеологизм оформляют как отдельное предложение: ***Не вертись, не списывай, не груби, не опаздывай!.." И так далее, и тому подобное… В школе будь человеком! [Валерий Медведев. Баранкин, будь человеком! (1957)]*** (пример из Нацкорпуса)

Comment: Bаши расуждения, на мой, взглад, очень логичны, но как быть с тем нелогичным указанием, которое оставил нам Розенталь (§ 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)?

Comment: А вот Грамота: Ответ справочной службы русского языка. 
Слова _и так далее, и тому подобное_ (и их сокращения) не выступают в роли однородных членов предложения, запятая перед ними не ставится: _Во время Адвента в первое воскресенье зажигают одну свечу, во второе – две и так далее_.

Comment: Спасибо, эта статья мной прочитана, другие подобного содержания тоже. Проблема в том, что содержание некоторых статей спорно. Соглашусь, что "и так далее" не является однородным членом предложения никак, а "и тому подобное" лишь замещает какой-то однородный член. А вот запятая перед "и так далее" должна ставиться, а перед "и тому подобное" - нет.

Comment: Прочитала в справочнике Розенталя статью. Вот она:"Слова и т. д. (и так далее), и т. п. (и тому подобное) не выступают в роли однородных членов предложениями, запятая перед ними не ставится, даже если союз и повторяется перед предшествующими однородными членами: В этот цикл естественных наук входят и биология, и физика, и химия и т. д., На выставку можно представить и рисунки, и этюды, и наброски и т. п." Обратите внимание, что приводятся сокращённые обозначения этих выражениий, полные высказывания даны в скобках. Перед сокращениями действительно запятую ставить не  надо.

Comment: Если бы Розенталь подразумевал разный подход к полной и сокращенной форме, он бы это явно указал, а не вводил нас в заблуждение пояснением в скобках. А Грамота пишет еще яснее.

Comment: Согласна. В ответе я руководствовалась только своими соображениями, опираясь на правила пунктуации при однородных членах и при оформлении сложных предложений. Возможно, я не права. А о Грамоте я боюсь судить).

Comment: Повторюсь: мне Ваш подход нравится своей логичностью, но мы не можем идти против указаний Розенталя, даже если они нам не по душе.

Comment: Почему же не можем?) Всё течёт, всё меняется, развивается, совершенствуется, уточняется. Тем более что ясности в данном случае всё-таки нет, указания оформлены не совсем чётко и конкретно (я имею в виду скобки). У нас есть право подвергать сомнению содержание высказываний, независимо от того, кому они принадлежат. Вариативность оформления письменной речи в русском языке настолько велика, что каждый сложный случай вызывает порой даже противоположные суждения, и это нормально. Это очень интересно! За это, может быть, мы и любим русский язык как науку.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном вами примере фраза «в английском языке есть слово blank 'пустой'» является предложением (в составе сложного предложения). Поэтому она должна отделяться запятыми, в том числе и от «и так далее».